# Using SerialPort to discard RF Device Buffer

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I'm writting a small application that automatically connects to the correct serial port by sending a list of commands, and then waiting for a response back from the serial device (RF Transmitter). The serial port objects sends certain commands in decimal format, a reset, login and then a query command.

When the query command is sent, the device then replies back with a response - when this response is received I know I have the correct serial port connection.

All of this works fine, but sometimes I receive an error back from the device - `Error 130: TX Queue Overflow`. This error can be resolved by simply restarted the device (RF Transmitter), but the frequency of this error is just silly.

Am I correct in thinking that a TX Overflow error would be caused when the buffer on the hardware becomes full? I thought a simple `DiscardInBuffer` just after opening a connection to the device would fix this - but it doesn't.

When should I use the `DiscardInBuffer`, am I using it in the correct context?

-- Edit

After some more comments and thoughts, I've come to the conclusion that the `SerialPort.DiscardInBuffer` won't do anything for my current situation, rather I need to discard the buffer on the actual RF Device - Hence why inplugging it works.

Comment: When you say "I receive an error back from the device - `Error 130: TX Queue Overflow`", what exactly do you mean? Is the device sending that string to you? What is this piece of hardware? Have you read its manual? It sounds like this has absolutely nothing to do with the serial port / .NET side of things.

Comment: Yes. The RF Device is sending this back to me. You can find the manual here:
http://www.conradt.com/fileadmin/Download/manuals/TN9000_manual.pdf

Comment: Did you see the comment in the manual for that error? *Overflow in dataset transmit queue. Refer to the specifications for the maximum number of datapackets in the queue. Use the command “reset txqueue” to clear the queue..*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've sent too much data to the device, and its output queue has overflowed, meaning it is not able to forward the data as fast as you're providing it.

There's no method you can call on the `SerialPort` class to fix this, these are two completely different buffers we're talking about. Calling `SerialPort.DiscardOutBuffer` will only discard the output data pending for *your serial port*, not the device.

To temporarily fix the issue, the manual indicates that you can:

> Use the command “reset txqueue” to clear the queue.

The better solution, however, is to prevent the issue and not flood the device with data. The exact way to do this will depend on your hardware.

One way might be to introduce some sort of `CommandQueue` class which has an associated `SerialPort` object to push the commands to the hardware. In this class, you could queue up commands to be sent, and send them out a configurable maximum rate. You would use a timer, and only send commands out if one hasn't been sent in the last X msec.

Another way would be to implement some sort of software flow control. It appears that your device supports querying the queue length with the `"?STATE"` command ([page 13](http://www.conradt.com/fileadmin/Download/manuals/TN9000_manual.pdf)). It will respond with:

```
 STATE x1/x2 x3 x4

 x1: Number of datapackets in TX queue
 x2: Size of TX queue
 x3: Status byte (8 bit hexadecimal)
 Normal state: status byte = 0
 Bit 0 = 1: Error in transceiver
 Bit 1 = 1: Error in EEPROM
 x4: Current value of the dataset counter (number of last received and saved datapacket)
```

You could query this before attempting to send a data packet, and simply sleep while the queue is full.

---

Having written a lot of code to interface with finicky hardware (Serial, Ethernet, etc.) in C#, I can offer the following advice:

- Implement an `abstract class TN9000DeviceBase` which has `abstract` methods for all of the commands supported by the device.
- Derive a `class TN9000SerialDevice : TN9000DeviceBase` which executes the command using serial port.

This will allow you to come back and implement it via Ethernet when requirements change.

Comment: I've tried to use `port.WriteLine("Login 1 123");` to login to RF, then I can clear the TXqueue `port.WriteLine("Reset TXQueue");`. Unfortunately is comes back stating access denied - I know for a fact that the password 123 is correct.

I already have a timing system in place. On every 500 milliseconds the timers tick event is raised with a counter stating what is to be sent next.

Comment: Thank you for that `?STATE` command. I'll be able to use this command to figure out when i'll need to clear the queue on the device! Thanks

Comment: @JohnathanBrown You're welcome. However, I wouldn't clear the queue, I would simply wait for the hardware to finish transmitting before sending it additional data packets.

Comment: It seems like you might have some other issue then. Having a method which returns the state of the hardware is always a Good Idea anyway. In fact, you can easily abstract away all of the device commands like this, to give yourself a good base to build the communications logic from.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. My plan when I got this port testing completed was to create a class which has every possible device response, then after each command I was going to query the response, get the logic back and then the program will decide what to do next.

Comment: Figured out exactly what happens and how to fix it in software.

If the device the RF transmitter is offline / standby / sleep mode, then the data to be transmitted is stored in the buffer. If the device the transmitter wants to talk too is then turned on / woken up the data isn't resent.

To fix this, I don't even need to call reset TXQueue. Rather, I just call `restart` twice. This clears the buffer and once again allows communication.

Comment: Glad to hear you've figured it out.